# How to encode a transaction offline？

Tags: encoding, offline

I'm writing an offline signature program without rpc,i have to encode transaction into bytes and I want to know the encoding rules.

What should the tag parameter fill in?
Under what circumstances do parameters need to be used？If I don't use it, do I need a placeholder?
What order to use？BIG_ENDIAN or LITTLE_ENDIAN？
In short, I want to know how I can generate bytes that can be signed.
My English is not very good, I hope you can understand what I express.

Comment: this library will probably help you https://github.com/tezbridge/tezbridge-crypto